# question about my mesh

Tags: modeling, uv, game-engine

My trouble areas are highlighted in red [pic included]. First off what are these extra edges there for?, what did i do and how do i get rid of them [should i wait to cut the holes out until i'm positive i'm done with that section of the model?. And second the overhang roof sections are not present in UE4 they're gone from the mesh. And any tips for creating a model for ue4 any links or info you can direct me to?.[image: heres the pic showing my issue]

Comment: You can't remove any edge in Blender, because it can't make any kind of shape for a face. You can remove an extra edge, if select it, hit x and select dissolve edge. If this doesn't work probably you can't get rid off that edge, but it's not a big problem. Under the dark purple roof's normals are facing to the wrong direction. Select all of the roof in edit mode, then select Mesh>Normals>Flip Normals.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. So just to clarify those ugly lines lol won't have an affect on my model when uv unwrapping or importing to an external engine like unreal engine 4?. Also should i uv-unwrap the entire model when it's done or should i do that to each piece as it's completed individually?.

Comment: These kind of shapes may cause strange results at unwrapping. If this does, try the projection from view option in the Unwrap menu. It doesn't count when you unwrap the models.

Comment: I have another question do i need to uv-unwrap or can you just select each piece of the model individually and apply the desired material?

Comment: The simpliest way if you unwrap everything if you use ordinary shaders.

Comment: @Mingo Upload your model here and I will make an example repair using your model, so that you can do it for yourself, so you can improve your concepts and better understand how the Boolean works, [upload blend stack exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Blender Blackened. That would be great but it'll be a few days as i lost that original file :[. But i've built this thing a couple times now because i'm new to blender and modeling and chose this particular structure as my practice tool. It's the church from the Netflix show DARK and i'm also looking to do the interior soon.